Get Gnome Boxes to recognize guest created in Virt-manager
I have a Windows 10 guest that I created in Virt-manager, it has a qcow2 virtual disk that is stored in a non-default location. It is actually on a different partition altogether.
How can I get Gnome Boxes to see this virtual machine?
The host is MX Linux 23 KDE (Debian-based)
What I tried:
I created a new VM in Boxes by pointing the wizard to my virtual disk.
It spun up a VM really fast, but it assigned all my CPU cores to the VM, and also, I can't get my smb network share in Dolphin to work. So it is obviously not replicating my Virt-manager settings.
